# What do you call the action of making desserts?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

A person who makes desserts is called a pastry chef, but is there a name for the action itself of making desserts?
"Cooking" is too general, and "baking" implies bread, cakes, etc. which is not quite what I mean.
Any ideas?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that by "an interest" you mean the vocation or the action of making pastries?

Comment: yes that's right - as in "I enjoy dessert-making". I just wanted a more formal term for this

Comment: But it's the *dessert-making* you would like an alternate term for, not the *enjoyment of dessert-making*?  If so, you might want to edit your question a little, because it currently sounds like you're asking about the affection for dessert making rather than the act itself.

Comment: I did mean the act itself, I've edited the question now

Comment: I would coin: dessertation or dessertion :)

Comment: How about Tartology?

Comment: "desserting"? oh wait.. :P

Comment: Would turning the raw ingredients into a food product be **dessertification**?

Comment: Hungarian has a word for the occupation: *cukrász*, which comes from *cukor* "sugar" + *-ász* "one who works with or is an expert in". (Noun and verb forms follow naturally: cukrászság, cukrászkodás.) A parallel English construction would be something like "sugarer". If that doesn't work for you, you can always just move to Hungary. :)

Comment: @Marthaª I like that a lot :) I suppose one could be a "sugar **worker**" in English, if they were an expert in spun sugar decorations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cooking school, [Le Cordon-Bleu USA](http://www.lecordonbleu-usa.com/Home/Programs%20and%20Tuition/Certificate%20in%20Baking%20and%20Pastry), refers to the field as the **pâtisserie and baking arts**. It also uses the term **pastry arts**.

The [Culinary Institute of America](http://www.ciachef.edu/associate-degree-baking-and-pastry-arts-ny/) uses the same phrases.

Comment: I like addition of **arts**! - the meaning of the term is still clear but it sounds a bit better than "pastry **making**"

Answer (score 1):

French here. The word you're looking for is [pâtisserie](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patisserie) making.

Actually, as long as all desserts are not pastries, the term "[entremet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entremet) making" would fit better than "pâtisserie making" here.

Comment: I was trying to find an alternative to "x making", ideally a single word

Comment: @Paige I can't seem to think of a single word to refer to patisserie making. I'll mull over that question and will let you know if I get an answer. :-)

Comment: I know someone who agrees that fruit does not count as a dessert!

Answer (score 1):

This question is looking for a verb. The verb is *confection*:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confection#Related_terms

In noun form, a confection is an edible thing made with sugar. In order to create a confection, you would first need to *confect* it, similar to the way that "perfection" is possessed by that which has been "perfected."

Example: "Have you *confected* those lemon bars yet?"
or:
"*Confection* is easy. You just put your hand around the icing tube... and squeeeeeze."
or:
"Don't make so much noise when I'm *confecting*!

Comment: This is incorrect. While a confection is an edible thing made with sugar, the verb form does not have the meaning of making such a thing. It has a broader meaning of mixing/compounding materials, not necessarily for desserts.

Comment: I suppose you're right. Frankly, I'm disappointed that such a word doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since each dessert might involve different processes to create, the all-inclusive **"preparing dessert"** seems like it will fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

**Cofectioning**: *verb, archaic* The act of making confections (separate from the medical term).

Out of use in English by 16th century, but now is as good a time as any to bring it back.

[Dictionary.com]

Answer (score 0):

I think "confectionist" has a nice sound to it! Hopefully, this isn't a word already and just dessert makers have their right to use it! Great question, I was thinking the same thing!
Good luck on future questions and endeavors,
Another Confectionist.

Answer (score -3):

This would be called an *interest in dessert making*.

If you want to coin a term:  **Dessertophilia** or **Pastrophilia**.

Granted these could merely be a love of desserts or pastries, but I still would call them applicable.

Comment: A -philia would be a more pronounced sexual interest in desserts in that context, iirc. Crustology might be more applicable, as it combines the Latin 'crustulum' [pastry] with the Latin suffix 'logia' [branch of learning]. I also note 'Bellaria' is the Latin for dessert. So someone interested in pastry making would be a Crustologist and someone specifically interested in desserts would be a Bellariologist? 
I think I'm done coining terms for one day...

Comment: so "bellariology" or "crustology" might work, then

Comment: @NinjaDuckie So, [Anglophiles](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anglophilia) are sexually interested in the British?  [Audiophiles](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/audiophilia) are sexually interested in audio?  Shall I keep going?

Comment: @David Touché. I shall research further before making assumptive points in future.